# Understanding FROM_REF_SPEED_LIMIT and TO_REF_SPEED_LIMIT attributes

Tags: here-api

I want to get speed limits for points in a car track. But instead of one value, I got two: FROM_REF_SPEED_LIMIT and TO_REF_SPEED_LIMIT. What is the meaning of these ones? Where is no documentation about these attributes. How can I use them to get speed limit? Actually speed limit in this place is 40km/h.

```
import requests

t = [(55.662026, 37.773537),
     (55.661813, 37.774049)]

s = ""

for x in t:
    s += ' <trkpt lat="' + str(x[0]) + '" lon="' + str(x[1]) + '"/> '

s1 = '<?xml version="1.0"?> <gpx version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd"> <trk>  <trkseg>  ' + s +'</trkseg></trk></gpx>'

resp = requests.post('http://rme.cit.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?routemode=carHOV&attributes=SPEED_LIMITS_FCn%28FROM_REF_SPEED_LIMIT,TO_REF_SPEED_LIMIT%29&app_id=iqZ08RnLQHOCQUYqwZ&app_code=oWWPJv9pVx9Y2DdIBBOA', data=s1)
print(resp.text)
```

Response:

```
{
    "MapVersion": "LATEST",
    "RouteLinks": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "SPEED_LIMITS_FCN": [
                    {
                        "FROM_REF_SPEED_LIMIT": "20",
                        "TO_REF_SPEED_LIMIT": "60"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "confidence": 0.94,
            "functionalClass": 3,
            "linkId": -1154810237,
            "linkLength": 50.75,
            "mSecToReachLinkFromStart": 3501,
            "offset": 0.42156,
            "shape": "55.66226 37.77328 55.66212 37.77352 55.66195 37.77387"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "SPEED_LIMITS_FCN": [
                    {
                        "FROM_REF_SPEED_LIMIT": "20",
                        "TO_REF_SPEED_LIMIT": "60"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "confidence": 0.95,
            "functionalClass": 3,
            "linkId": -1154810236,
            "linkLength": 58.13,
            "mSecToReachLinkFromStart": 6403,
            "offset": 0.69481,
            "shape": "55.66195 37.77387 55.66179 37.77431 55.66168 37.77466"
        }
    ],
    "TracePoints": [
        {
            "confidenceValue": 0.5,
            "elevation": 0.0,
            "headingDegreeNorthClockwise": 10000.0,
            "headingMatched": 131.0,
            "lat": 55.662026,
            "latMatched": 55.66208,
            "linkIdMatched": -1154810237,
            "lon": 37.773537,
            "lonMatched": 37.77361,
            "matchDistance": 10.0,
            "matchOffsetOnLink": 0.42156269739402924,
            "minError": 7.0,
            "routeLinkSeqNrMatched": 0,
            "speedMps": 0.0,
            "timestamp": 0
        },
        {
            "confidenceValue": 0.58,
            "elevation": 0.0,
            "headingDegreeNorthClockwise": 10000.0,
            "headingMatched": 123.0,
            "lat": 55.661813,
            "latMatched": 55.66186,
            "linkIdMatched": -1154810236,
            "lon": 37.774049,
            "lonMatched": 37.77411,
            "matchDistance": 8.59,
            "matchOffsetOnLink": 0.69481133508979,
            "minError": 7.0,
            "routeLinkSeqNrMatched": 1,
            "speedMps": 0.0,
            "timestamp": 0
        }
    ],
    "Warnings": []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link has two different speed limits for each direction in its map data.
If the published speed limit is wrong, you can report it to https://mapcreator.here.com. Right now we will take a look at it. 
Please check the attached image.
Thank you!
[image]

Comment: If `linkId` is negative, does it means that my car route and your's in opposite directions?

Comment: Negative/Plus in Link ID means travel direction. -1154810237 means A to B direction.Speed Limit sources can differ per travel direction.

Comment: As per documentation:

  'FROM_REF_SPEED_LIMIT': "If all columns apply to a vehicle, this is the speed limit (in km/h) on this link in the direction of 'from reference node to nonreference node'. The reference node is the node with the lower left latitude (and z level).",
  'TO_REF_SPEED_LIMIT': "If all columns apply to a vehicle, this is the 'towards reference node' speed limit (in km/h) on this link."},

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport: I believe negative link id means traveling to the reference point. Which is A in this case, so -1154810237 should mean B to A direction.

This is also visible on screenshot where B to A is 60 km/h and original data says `"TO_REF_SPEED_LIMIT": "60"`